# model selection, mixture of Gaussians

Tags: model-selection, likelihood, gaussian-mixture-distribution, bic

I have data and I want to decide whether it comes from 5-modal-normal distribution or 2-modal-normal distribution. In other words I want to check if it has 2 peaks or 5. I can estimate the $\mu$ and $\sigma$ of each Gaussian, but I don't know how to calculate the likelihood of each model. When I do, I would like to use the BIC criterion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normal distributions always have one mode, not 2 or 5. Presumably you mean to ask about how to calculate the likelihood of normal mixtures.

Since the density of a finite mixture is readily calculated from the densities of the components and the probability-weights on each component,

$$p(y_i|\underline{\mu},\underline{\sigma}^2,\underline{\pi}) = \sum_{j=1}^k \pi_i\,f(y_i|\mu_j,\sigma_j^2)\,,$$

if you have maximum likelihood (ML) estimates of the component means and standard deviations and component-weights, the likelihood of the mixture is straightforward, as is counting the parameters (there are normally $3k-1$ parameters for $k$ components - $2k$ for the mean and variance parameters by component and $k-1$ for the component weights); the likelihood is just

$$\prod_i p(y_i|\underline{\hat \mu},\underline{\hat \sigma}^2,\underline{\hat \pi})$$

Note that Steele and Raftery (2010) [1] says

> For regular models, BIC is
>   derived as an approximation to twice the log integrated likelihood using the Laplace method
>   (Tierney and Kadane 1986), but the necessary regularity conditions do not hold for mixture
>   models in general (Aitkin and Rubin 1985). However, Roeder and Wasserman (1997) showed
>   that BIC leads to to a consistent estimator of the mixture density, and Keribin (2000) showed
>   that BIC is consistent for choosing the number of components
>   in a mixture model.

Indeed, it performs very well (see the same reference).

[1] Steele, R.J. and Raftery, A.E. (2010).
"Performance of Bayesian Model Selection Criteria for Gaussian Mixture Models."
In *Frontiers of Statistical Decision Making and Bayesian Analysis*
(M.-H. Chen et al eds), p 113-130,
New York: Springer
[working paper version from 2009](https://www.stat.washington.edu/research/reports/2009/tr559.pdf)